# Can we ingest the sst files from one RocksDB to another RocksDB?

Tags: rocksdb

There is a `ingestExternalFile()` I found in RocksDB API. But when I try to ingest sst files from one RocksDB to another RocksDB, it give me the blow exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: External file version not found
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.ingestExternalFile(Native Method)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.ingestExternalFile(RocksDB.java:2142)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

There will be mismatch in File versions, CF ids and sequence numbers when you try to do that. Usually, SSTs to ingest are created using SSTFileWriter. This writer sets the SEQUENCE IDs of all the rows in the SST and the `global sequence number` to 0. When this SST file gets ingested, the db assigns a suitable global sequence number to this file after ingesting. 
When ingesting SST from db to db, this will cause problems.
Ingesting a compacted SST file from one rocks instance to another might come up in future versions.